# Postfix - virtual - exclude sender from recipients

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-10.04, virtualization, mailman

Is postfix able to rewrite the recipients, based on the sender address?

There are multiple users receiving Mail by this configuration in `/etc/postfix/virtual`:

```
mail@example.com        user1, user2, user3, user4
```

But whenever user*X* sends a mail@example.com, user*X* receives its own mail.

Is Mailman the right Tool for this job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postfix itself can't exclude sender from the alias. The reason is the lookup just has one parameter, either sender or recipient.

---

Mailman is a mailing lists manager. **Yes** it has functionality to forward email to members list as your example above. As a bonus, mailman has [advanced feature of mailing list](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/features.html) like list-admin, members management, bounce management and archiving.

Your request to exclude sender to get his own message, mailman has it too. Take a look to [this thread](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/mailman-users/2011-February/071118.html) and [this one](http://grokbase.com/t/python/mailman-users/05aa6vhyb2/members-not-receiving-their-own-posts). Basically, you should set option **Do not send a copy of a member's own post** in mailman list.

One caveats: if you use mailman in [virtual domain environment](http://www.list.org/mailman-install/postfix-virtual.html), it has limitation. Suppose you have domain example.com and example.net, then you can't have both lists@example.com and lists@example.net because [listname must be globally unique within](http://www.list.org/mailman-install/postfix-virtual.html) a single Mailman instance, i.e., two lists may not have the same name even if they are in different domains.